# How to increase the automatic line-wrap margin in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Emacs automatically wraps the line when a certain margin is reached. This margin also applies for the `M-q` (realign paragraph) command. This margin seems to be around 70 characters. How do I increase this margin?

Comment: Have a look at the variable `fill-column` -- type `M-x describe-variable RET fill-column RET`  Note that this is not really a margin and this is not really word-wrapping -- instead, Emacs is inserting a hard-return -- aka `\n` -- based on the modes that are enabled and a certain column number.

Comment: @lawlist put this as an answer and get voted up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the variable `fill-column` controls the column number at which certain modes automatically insert a hard-return -- aka `\n` -- when typing a long line.  To the extent that the `fill-column` is set prior to the margin, the margin setting is irrelevant.  To read more about the `fill-column`, type `M-x describe-variable RET fill-column RET`

Emacs has built-in support for `word-wrap` (when said variable is set to `t`), which wraps whole words for long lines that reach the window edge/fringe/margin -- **without** inserting hard-returns.  This is different than the concept/mechanism discussed above.